# jQuery keep-alive with actions

Tags: jquery, session, keep-alive

I'm trying to write a jQuery script which checks to see if the user has clicked, scrolled, or hit a key within the last minute.  If so, it should show an alert at the next interval (1-minute).  If not, it will still show an alert every 1-minute interval as long as the page has been loaded within 1 hour.

This seems like it should work, but it's not.  Any ideas:

```
$(function() {

        var initialPageLoad = new Date().getTime();
        var lastSiteAction = 0;
        var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
           if(Date().getTime() - lastSiteAction > 60000){
               if(Date().getTime() - initialPageLoad > 3601000){
                   clearInterval(checkInterval);
               }else{
                   alert('Tried to checkin!  You have not done anything in the last minute.');
               }
           }else{
                alert('Tried to checkin!  You have done something in the last minute.')
           }
        }, 60000); // 1 mins * 60 * 1000

        $(document).keydown(function(){
             lastSiteAction = new Date().getTime();
        });
        $(document).scroll(function(){
             lastSiteAction = new Date().getTime();
        });
        $(document).mousedown(function(){
             lastSiteAction = new Date().getTime();
        });

        alert('loaded!');
    });
```

Comment: Why are you clearing the interval check after 1 hour (regardless of any interaction)?

Comment: Because the site session expires after one hour and I don't need this to keep checking to see if they're active.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems flawed in a number of ways, not least because you are checking every minute if the user has interacted. Consider that the user interacted 1 second before the check. The first check (59 seconds after the user interacted) does nothing, then the second check at 1:59 displays the alert. The user has been inactive for nearly two minutes, not 1.

How about this as a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xAzNN/5/

Comment: That actually is a really nice code, and helped me with another problem thanks Grezzo.

I should have mentioned the following:

- this code is only ran if the user is logged in
- in place of the alerts, the final code will be pinging a file which updates the "last_activity" field of a database... therefore I need to do it at set intervals instead of ONLY when the user is actually inactive.

Comment: I actually have the timer successfully working now after some modification.  Now my problem is $.get, doesn't seem to work.  I also tried .ajax which DID work, but kept pinging the file every second in an infinite loop... which I don't want.`code`$.get("<?= site_url('checkin'); ?>", function(){
                            return;
                        });

Comment: No problem. I see... I'm afraid it's been some time since I dealt with any jQuery ajax, any ajax at all really (I only learned jQuery  and ajax as a way to get a hobby webapp built), so I might not be able to help you there. Perhaps start another question?